# Bad Request - Invalid URL IIS Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, iis

My URL is working on Apache and xampp but when I moved this
project to IIS server then this URL is giving error 400.

Bad Request - Invalid URL HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

I have created 4 files in
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`

```
AllowRestrictedChars = 1 EnableNonUTF8 = 1 MaxFieldLength = 16348
MaxRequestBytes = 16348
```

Then also it is giving 400 error, please help.

[image: bad request screenshot]

Comment: https://ccnavigator.app/videoConnected/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJTSzMzYzNjZjljY2QxNTEwY2U3YjQ5MDY3YjcxYzljOTY2LTE1OTM3NzIzMjQiLCJpc3MiOiJTSzMzYzNjZjljY2QxNTEwY2U3YjQ5MDY3YjcxYzljOTY2Iiwic3ViIjoiQUMyN2EyOGRhNDE4N2ZlODJjODliNTM0NTJhMWJjYTkzNSIsImV4cCI6MTU5Mzc3NTkyNCwiZ3JhbnRzIjp7ImlkZW50aXR5IjoiSm9obiBTbWl0aCBMOTkyODgyMSIsInZpZGVvIjp7InJvb20iOiJKb2huU21pdGhMNTc3NTQxNiJ9fX0.9mGZ2E_9CSaOM7CCLwmWY2WEx9YXzSHbquYEyXreiRY/video/358/JohnSmithL5775416

Comment: This was my URL show 400 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make short your URL as possible as short.

set request filtering value for max URL length:

[image]

Comment: I have tried to set request filtering value for max URL length as you have told, but it didn't worked.

Comment: @Shantanuyadav you could try to make short your URL as possible as short.

Comment: Yes, I have made the url shorter and it worked.
Thanks Jalpa.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the following value to the following:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters -Name UrlSegmentMaxLength -Value 2000 -Type "Dword"
```

You will need to restart the machine for the changes to take effect.